# Discord.js Adding multiple buttons using raw API request

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Not 100% sure if I'm doing this right but it looks like the second component (line 13)
does not get recognized or something

am I doing this wrong or did I miss something?
I tried following the documentation [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/message-components#buttons)
but couldn't figure it out,

I just think my brain is just broken haha

I would appreciate the help

**This is for the buttons using Discord.js 12.5.3**

```js
client.api.channels(applicationChannelId).messages.post({
   data: {
    embeds: [application],
   components: [{
    type: 1,
//accept button
   components: [{
    type: 2,
    style: 3,
    label: "Accept",
    custom_id: "accept",
//deny button
   components: [{
    type: 2,
    style: 4,
    label: "Deny",
    custom_id: "deny"
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.components` accepts an array of MessageComponents  so instead of trying to add multiple values of `components` you can just add it to an array like so:

```js
client.api.channels(applicationChannelId).messages.post({
   data: {
    embeds: [application],
   components: [{
    type: 2,
    style: 3,
    label: "Accept",
    custom_id: "accept"},
  {
    type: 2,
    style: 4,
    label: "Deny",
    custom_id: "deny"
      },
]})
```

Comment: you are the true MVP man, My brain does not want to work at full capacity at times. Thanks a million

Comment:  no issues my dude